# how update Jtextfield text simultaneously when typing on it?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField.I want  after each character the user types,a method call and change the order of character in same JTextField,but in my code displayArrestNo2() method call and print in consol right answer but dont update content of JTextField.How can do it?

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {


         final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setSize(100, 100);
            textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {  
                try{

          Stringx=displayArrestNo2(e.getDocument().getText(0,e.getDocument().getLength()));
                    System.out.println(x);



                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


           }

      public void warn() {   
      }
          public  String displayArrestNo2(String aValue){
                   System.out.println("oroginal value: " + aValue);
          aValue = " "+aValue+" ";
          System.out.println("space added value: "+aValue);
          final String validStr = " ابپتثجچحخدرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهیي";
        int lPos, fPos, i, j, k;
        boolean flgEnterIntSection, lastWasChar;
        String result = "";

        flgEnterIntSection= false;
          lastWasChar = false;
          lPos = 0;
          i = aValue.length()-1;
          while( i >= 0) {
             char[] aValueArr = aValue.toCharArray();
             /* char[] tmpArr = aValue.toCharArray();
              char[] aValueArr = new char[tmpArr.length];
              for(int x=0; x<tmpArr.length; x++)
                  aValueArr[x]= tmpArr[tmpArr.length-x-1]; */

              if (aValueArr[i] == 'ß')
                  aValueArr[i] = '˜'; 

              if (convert(aValueArr[i]) == -1)
              {
                  if(validStr.indexOf(aValueArr[i]) > 0)
                  {
                      j = 0;
                      while ( ( (i - j) > 0) && (validStr.indexOf(aValueArr[i-j]) > 0 ))
                          j = j + 1;

                          if (j >1)//j>1 
                          {
                              k = j;
                              while (j > 0) 
                              {
                                result =  result + aValueArr[i - j+1];//i-j+1
                                j--;
                              }
                              i = i - k+1;//i-k+1
                            }
                            else
                              result = result + aValueArr[i];
                            }
                        else
                          result = result + aValueArr[i];
                        i--;
                        flgEnterIntSection = false;
                        }

              else
                {
                  fPos = i;
                  j = i;
                  while ((j >= 0) && ((!flgEnterIntSection) || (convert(aValueArr[j]))!=-1))// (StrToIntDef(AValue[j], -1) <> -1)
                  {
                    flgEnterIntSection = true;
                    while ((j >= 0) && (convert(aValueArr[j]))!=-1) // StrToIntDef(AValue[j], -1) <> -1)
                      j--;
                    if ((j > 0) && ((aValueArr[j] == '.') || (aValueArr[j] == '/')) )
                      if (((j-1) >= 0) && (convert(aValueArr[j-1]))!=-1)  //StrToIntDef(AValue[j - 1], -1) <> -1)
                        j--;
                  }
                  lPos = j + 1;

                    for (j = lPos; j <= fPos; j++)

                    {
                        result = result + aValueArr[j];
                    }
                    i = lPos-1;
                }
          }

    //  return result;
        //  System.out.println("before reverse "+result);
          return reverseOrder(result);
    }

     String reverseOrder(String input){
         String [] inArr = input.split(" ");
         String reversed = "";
         for(int i = inArr.length-1;  i>=0; i--){
             reversed += inArr[i] + " ";
         }
         return reversed;
     }

        public int convert(char ch) {

            try {
                int m = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch));
                return m;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }

        }

              TestJTextField x=new TestJTextField();
                    x.add(textField);
                   x.setVisible(true);                 
    }
```

in insertUpdate() method ,displayArrestNo2() is called per character but dont change content of JTextField.

Comment: because when type persian character, order of previous  changes.

Comment: Ah.. right.  I had not realized that!  Could you [edit that information into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33332859/edit)?  That way, no one will have to sit there, wondering what I did.  :P